# MAPI APIs to save appointment do not save changes if process killed

Tags: outlook-addin, mapi

I am trying to develop a COM plugin with vc++ for outlook which receives data from a non exchange server and saves them to Outlook PST files.

I am using Outlook object model and MAPI APIs to save an appointment object in the message store. I save the item using Outlook::_AppointmentItem::save() method. after this I set some properties for this through the IMessage interface and call savechanges() on it.

It works fine in normal condition. But if the outlook process is killed immediately after the event is added, on restart the changes are lost. Looks like outlook takes some time saving the changes to disk. This behavior is creating some other problems.

Is there any way I can flush the changes to disk immediately after save. Need help on this

Answer (score 0):

The PST provider flushes the chnages as it sees fit.
The only way to force the flush is to use the [IMAPIClientShutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd941348) interface, but after you do that, the whole MAPI system is shutdown, so nothing will work until the process is restartyed.